# Power BI: Count multiple values in column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm working with the dataset where the gender of all participants is described in one single column. I'd like to create two new columns for both genders and fill it up with the number of males / females involved.

The syntax used in a column looks like this:

`0::Male||1::Male||3::Male||4::Female`

(so we have 4 participants, the value in col "Male" would be 3, in col "Female" 1)

Would you be so kind and help me to extract this information? ♥

I'm sorry to ask you as I know I'd be able to eventually find the solution by myself, but I'm really under pressure right now. :/

[This is the screenshot of the column I wanna extract values from.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7B7v.png)

Thanks a lot to everyone who tries to help! :)

Comment: Please provide sample data, and what you have tried. The screenshot isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In powerquery, you'd need two splits (one on :: and one on ||, and then a pivot to get data into right format)

Select your data, including header column of participant_gender and load your table into powerquery with Data ... From Table/Range...[x] my data has headers.  I assume below that this is the first table of your file, and is named Table1

Add Column..Index Column...

right click participant_gender column ... split column ... by delimiter ... custom ... || [x] each occurrence of the delimiter , Advanced options [x] rows

right click participant_gender column ... split column ... by delimiter ... custom ... :: [x] each occurrence of the delimiter (ignore advanced options)

Click to select both participant_gender.2 and Index columns .. right click group by ... group by (participant_gender.2) (index) new column name (count) operation (sum) column (participant_gender.1)

Click to select participant_Gender.2 column  ... Transform..pivot column...Values column (Count)

File...Close and Load to ... table

Code produced, which you can paste into Home .. Advanced Editor... if you wish

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"participant_gender", type text}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"participant_gender", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("||", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "participant_gender"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"participant_gender", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "participant_gender", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("::", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"participant_gender.1", "participant_gender.2"}),
#"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"participant_gender.1", Int64.Type}, {"participant_gender.2", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type2", {"participant_gender.2", "Index"}, {{"Count", each List.Sum([participant_gender.1]), type number}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[participant_gender.2]), "participant_gender.2", "Count", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```